# Can separable verbs be with 得?

Tags: grammar, phrase

I have two question involving 得. Please help me out.

1. I wonder if separable verbs (verb + object) can be with 得 without repeating the first verb. For example,

   > 她吃饭吃得很多。or 她饭吃得很多。

Because 吃饭 is a separable verb, so can I say: 她吃饭得很多 ?

2. **In YES/NO question with 得, are degree adverbs needed?**

   > A: 你今天起得**很早/早**吗？

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

在口语中

```
她吃饭吃得很多
她饭吃得很多   #宾语提前了，宾语放到谓语动词的前面了。
```

这两种说法都有，她饭吃得很多，这句话有点特别，通常这样说，她字和饭字之间，有一个很短暂的停顿。

Answer (score 0):

1.can I say: 她吃饭得很多 ? NO

2.are degree adverbs needed? It can be ignored.

A: 你今天起得很早/早吗？

B: 我今天起得很早。**(O)** B:  我今天起很早。**(O)**

Comment: oh I did not make it clear. The 2nd is to ask for degree adverbs in YES/NO question, not the answer: 你今天起得很早/早吗？

Answer (score 0):

> *1.can I say: 她吃饭得很多?*

No, If you use 得 with separable verb, you have to either 1. Repeat the first part of the separable verb, e.g. 她吃饭吃得很多.(meaning she can eat a lot rice)  2. put 得 between the separable verb. e.g. "她吃得饭多" (meaning she ate a lot of rice or she eat rice very often)

*"她饭吃得很多" has no separable verb (the only verb is 吃;  饭 is the object*

More Example:

> 讀書，唱歌，喝酒 are all separable verbs
>
> 她讀得書多，所以不怕找不到工作 (得 is inserted between the verb and object part of 讀書)
>
> 她唱得歌多，聲音也變得好聽了 (得 is inserted between the verb and object part of 唱歌)
>
> 她喝得酒多，說話有點含糊 (得 is inserted between the verb and object part of 喝酒)

~

> 她書讀得多，所以不怕找不到工作 (no separable verb, 書 is the object, 讀 is the verb)
>
> 她歌唱得多，聲音也變得好聽了 (no separable verb, 歌 is the object, 唱 is the verb)
>
> 她酒喝得多，說話有點含糊 (no separable verb, 酒 is the object, 喝 is the verb)

~

> *2.are degree adverbs needed?*

It is optional

Both 我今天起得早 (I woke up early today) and  我今天起得很早 (I woke up very early today) are legit sentences

Comment: oh I did not make it clear. The 2nd is to ask for degree adverbs in YES/NO question, not the answer: 你今天起得很早/早吗？

Comment: BTW, do you have any web sources involving that putting 得 between the separable verb? ("她吃得饭多")

Comment: optional mean either yes or no. Which mean Not required (but you can) .

Comment: See more examples  of 得 between the separable verb in my edition.

Comment: In case 得 is inserted between the verb and object, are there any notices? Can this structure apply for ALL separable verbs?

Comment: As long as it is made up of  v + n . Example: 殺人 --> 殺得人多 ; 打仗 --> 打得仗多; 造飯 -->造得飯多

Comment: The structure  of [V+得 +N ] is applied to [insert 得  between a  separable verb] . Simply put, we are treating a single separable verb as "verb and noun"

Answer (score 0):

(1) The question is: Can you insert 得 in the (verb + object = verb + noun) phrase? No. In this case, you use 的 before a noun.

For example, 她吃的饭很多. In this sentence 很多 is an adjective for the noun 饭.

In your sentence 她吃饭吃得很多, use 得 is correct. In this sentence 很多 is an adverb for the verb 吃, the second 吃).

(2) In YES/NO questions with 得, are degree adverbs needed? Yes, most likely.

Q: 你今天起得早吗？

A1: 是的，我今天起得很早。

A2: 是的，我今天起床的时间很早。

A3: 是的，我今天早早地就起床了。

In general, the structures of 的,得,地 are as the following:

(1) Adjective + 的 + Noun = Noun phrase = e.g. 这是红色的衣服。

(2) Noun + 的 + Noun = Compound noun phrase = e.g. 这是小红的衣服。

(3) Verb + 的 + Noun = VO phrase = e.g. 这是小红买的衣服。

(4) Verb + 得 + Adverb = Verb phrase = e.g. 这件衣服卖得太贵。

(5) Adverb + 地 + Verb = Verb phrase = e.g. 小红急切地想买这件衣服。